# Is it possible to restrict the AppSync API endpoint to in network only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-appsync

I'm currently building an AppSync API and will be implementing Cognito Pools for authorization. I noticed that there is an endpoint created upon building an AppSync API. It looks like with API Gateway, you can restrict public access to the endpoint using a VPC. Is there something similar that is available with AppSync so that the endpoint exposed is not accessible to the public?

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-endpoint-integrations-with-private-vpcs/

One thought is to attach the AppSync url to a custom domain that is not public. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Cognito User Pools, if you turn on Advanced Security Features, you can restrict authentication to specific network address ranges so basically you can restrict your users to authenticating only from specific network locations. With AWS AppSync, it is not possible currently to restrict access to specific IP addresses but it is a feature we are considering.

For having custom domains with AppSync you can have a look at the following blog post:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-a-custom-domain-with-aws-appsync-amazon-cloudfront-and-amazon-route-53/

Comment: So if the requirement is to not allow a public url, would AppSync not be an option then? Or would creating a custom domain for the appsync url satisfy that demand?

Comment: This functionality is on our roadmap. I guess if you wouldn't care if the AppSync generated app URL is still accessible.

Comment: This answer might need updating because with WAF you do have some additional control here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/WAF-Integration.html. It is still public, but you could block everything not from your network.

Comment: For me, the access to an AppSync API over a PrivateLink (or other mechanism internal to a VPC) is as much about performance as anything.  If I'm calling my AppSync API from other resources within my VPC, why would I want to traverse the Internet first?  Thanks for keeping this request high on the roadmap!

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible as of May 2023 - AWS announced Private AppSync APIs as GA this month.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/introducing-private-apis-on-aws-appsync/